# Is high liquidity required to fulfill DRIPs?

Tags: dividend-reinvestment, liquidity

With DRIPs you get equity instead of cash, but where is this equity coming from? If it's from the existing market then what happens in low liquidity situations?

Answer (score 1):

The company has the discretion to  either issue shares from the corporate treasury or acquire them in the open market at prevailing market prices.

Shares  purchased from the company creates more capital for the company to use and may  provided at a discount to the investor.